# Problem SPARQL Query - SELECT rdf:label WHERE {class rdf:someRelation otherClass}

Tags: nlp, sparql, owl, ontology

I want to query an ontology with SPARQL with the output from an NLP algorithm. The output are to lists one is nouns and the other one is verbs. Where nouns correspond to classes and verbs to Data properties. So when the relation `noun1 verb1 noun2` exists the label should be shown

Why do I want to extract the label? The label is not really important I just want to get one of the annotation from a class.

Why? I extract some nouns and verbs from reports. When I have the connection `noun1 verb1 noun2` in my ontology then I want to get the annotation of `noun2` because it has the solution for my case.

I use http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl for my tests. I believe my code does not work because of multiple problems.

First problem the query

```
SELECT ?label
    WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }
```

does not yield a result.
Second the query below does not yield a result.

```
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject rdfs:actsFor ?object }
```

So basically I do not understand how to write SPARQL queries...

In the end version I should be able to query something like

```
SELECT rdf:label
    WHERE { Agent rdfs:actsFor SocialAgent }
```

and get the label "Social agent"

I hope my question is not to confusing. I am new to SPARQL and ontologies. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `SELECT ?label
    WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }` - what do you expect to be returned? I mean, in the query body, you just have `?subject` and `?object`, so you can just select those variables. In general, SPARQL is a query language for RDF - RDF in fact consists of RDF triples, so in SPARQL you write so called triple patterns that match those RDF triples. If you want to have labels, then you have to add another triple pattern that gets those labels. So you have to add a second triple pattern to get the label either for `?subject` or `?object`

Comment: You can also think of it as subgraph matching. RDF is a graph and you want something out of the graph, an RDF triple is an edge and you have to define triple patterns that match those edges.

Comment: That said, don't use the pre-defined namespaces like `rdf` and `rdfs` for your own vocabulary. The proeprty `rdfs:actsFor` does not exist. But maybe first read about what prefixes in RDF are, or even better read about RDF and SPARQL first. You're missing fundamental things like, liek URIs, prefixed URIs, etc. - there are a bunch of RDF and SPARQL tutorials online

Comment: `SELECT ?label WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }` should have returened a label :-) So you basically say that I have to have a `?label` in a tripple in the WHERE part in order to use it in the SELECT part? I believe I think to much as if it is SQL
In Protege my queries never work if I do not use `rdf:actsFor` so `actsFor` would not work.

Comment: Not sure if you read or understood my comments, but the solutions are determined by the query body. Your query body consists of a single triple pattern `?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object` which has two variables `?subject` and `?object`, so you can do `SELECT ?subject` or `SELECT `?object` or `SELECT ?subject ?object` but nothing else. And I also told you that `rdfs` is a prefix of the pre-defined RDFS vocabulary. I'm not sure if you even know what a URI is nor what a prefixed URI is. You should read about both first. Clearly, the namespace of your ontology is different from the RDFS namespace.

Comment: In SQL you select columns of tables, in SPARQL you select variables that occur in the query body and it will return a non-empty result is the RDF graph has something that matches the pattern

Comment: I believe I now understand how to write a general query the way I want. Thank you! Do you know how to specify a for example certain class in the WHERE statement? like `WHERE {class1 relation class2}`?

Comment: in RDF everything is either a literal, a blank node or a resource identified by a URI. Classes should be URIs, so you have to use the URI.

Comment: Thank you, now I believe I understand my problems!